# format flare.jason from existing json

Tags: d3.js

I am formatting regular json data to a flare format for a chart I am working on and ran into an issue creating the children. I have a fiddle of my current work and was hoping someone could spot what I missed.

[not working](https://jsfiddle.net/jwaldner/1pucznsc/9/)
I only get it to return this [no children]:

```
[
{
  "parent": "new skill",
  "name": "Advanced",
  "AgtName": "amy"
},
{
  "parent": "new skill",
  "name": "Advanced",
  "AgtName": "GARY"
}
```

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using d3, you can use [d3.nest](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/README.md#nests) to get a hierarchical structure from an array. Here is a snippet based on your code:

```
let tree = d3.nest().key(node => node.name).entries(data);
```

Working [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/gc5uI0HGKEAXelVlFhud?p=preview)

Comment: Very cool!! Do you know if there is a way to change values: to children [or if I even need to??]